# Cassandra query table without partition key

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to extract data from a table as part of a migration job.

The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${keyspace}.entries (
    username text,

    entry_type int,

    entry_id text,

    PRIMARY KEY ((username, entry_type), entry_id)
);
```

In order to query the table we need the partition keys, the first part of the primary key.
Hence, if we know the `username` and the `entry_type`, we can query the table.

In this case the `username` can be whatever, but the `entry_type` is an integer in the range 0-9.

When doning the extraction we iterate the table 10 times for every username to make sure we try all versions of `entry_type`.

We can no longer find any entries as we have depleted our list of usernames. But our `nodetool tablestats` report that there is still data left in the table, gigabytes even. Hence we assume the table is not empty.

But I cannot find a way to inspect the table to figure out what usernames remains in the table. If I could inspect it I could add the usernames left in the table to our extraction job and eventually we could deplete the table. But I cannot simply query the table as such:

```
SELECT * FROM ${keyspace}.entries LIMIT 1
```

as cassandra requires the partition keys to make meaningful queries.

What can I do to figure out what is left in our table?

Comment: In the "extraction process" are you deleting the entries that you found? I'm trying to understand why are you expecting to not retrieve data. If you are deleting the records, are you considering the GC grace period (`gc_grace_seconds` setting) this will create a delay between the delete execution and when the record is actually removed from the system

Comment: Yes, for each record we find, we insert them into another table and then delete them from the table in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, I would like to put more light on ***gc_grace_seconds*** property.

In Cassandra, data isn’t deleted in the same way it is in RDBMSs. Cassandra is designed for high write throughput, and avoids reads-before-writes. So in Cassandra, a delete is actually an update, and updates are actually inserts. A **“tombstone”** marker is written to indicate that the data is now (logically) deleted  (also known as soft delete). Records marked tombstoned must be removed to claim back the storage space. Which is done by a process called **Compaction**. But remember that tombstones are eligible for physical deletion / garbage collection only after a specific number of seconds known as gc_grace_seconds. This is a very good blog to read more in detail : https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

Now possibly you are looking into table size before gc_grace_seconds and data is still there.

Coming to your second issue where you want to fetch some samples from the table without providing partition keys. You can analyze your table content using Spark. The Spark Cassandra Connector allows you to create Java applications that use Spark to analyze database data.  You can follow the articles / documentation to write a quick handy spark application to analyze Cassandra data.

https://www.instaclustr.com/support/documentation/cassandra-add-ons/apache-spark/using-spark-to-sample-data-from-one-cassandra-cluster-and-write-to-another/

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html

I would recommend not to delete records  while you do the migration. Rather first complete the migration and post that do a quick validation / verification to ensure all records are migrated successfully (this use can easily do using Spark buy comparing dataframes from old and new tables). Post successful verification truncate the old table as truncate does not create tombstones and hence more efficient. Note that huge no of tombstone is not good for cluster health.

Comment: I will have a look at spark!

As for the actual migration task; it has two stages, or two iterations if you will. First it inserts into the new table, then on the second pass it deletes from the old table when it finds matches in the new table.

The dataset we have to migrate shrinks for each time we run the task and it finds new candidates to migrate. The idea was that this would help speed up the process as we assumed we would have to run the task multiple times as Cassandra is partially consistent.

But still, thank you much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment, the migration process includes a DELETE operation from the Cassandra table, but the engine will have a delay before actually removing from disk the affected records; this process is controlled internally with tombstones and the `gc_grace_seconds` attribute of the table. The reason for this delay is fully explained in this [blog entry](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html), for a tl dr, if the default value is still in place, Cassandra will need to pass at least 10 days (864,000 seconds) from the execution of the delete before the actual removal of the data.

For your case, one way to proceed is:

1. Ensure that all your nodes are "Up" and "Healthy" (`UN`)
2. Decrease the gc_grace_seconds attribute of your table, in the example, it will set it to 1 minute, while the default is

   ALTER TABLE .entries with GC_GRACE_SECONDS = 60;
3. Manually compact the table:

   nodetool compact  entries
4. Once that the process is completed, `nodetool tablestats` should be up to date